# Remove \x01,\x02.....etc. from NSString after decode 3DES

Tags: ios, objective-c

For example:

Original Text: "123456"

3DES Encode Text: "VjARiuJ9BeE="

Decode 3DES: "123456\x02\x02"

how to remove characters like \x01,\x02...etc. ?

[image]

NSLog Know how to avoid those characters, but in variable still have \x01,\02...etc.

In python, have property string.printable can avoid those characters.

in iOS, how to avoid?

Thanks.

Comment: alternatively you can use AES with CommonCrypto  library if you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before

```
ccStatus = CCCrypt(kCCDecrypt,
                   kCCAlgorithm3DES,
                   kCCOptionPKCS7Padding & kCCModeCBC,
                   vkey,
                   kCCKeySize3DES,
                   vinitVec,
                   vplainText,
                   plainTextBufferSize,
                   (void *)bufferPtr,
                   bufferPtrSize,
                   &movedBytes);
```

After fix

```
ccStatus = CCCrypt(kCCDecrypt,
                   kCCAlgorithm3DES,
                   kCCOptionPKCS7Padding,
                   vkey,
                   kCCKeySize3DES,
                   vinitVec,
                   vplainText,
                   plainTextBufferSize,
                   (void *)bufferPtr,
                   bufferPtrSize,
                   &movedBytes);
```

I solve the problem,  PCKS7Padding default is CBC mode, no need to add &kCCModeCBC in code.

After remove &kCCModeCBC in code, i can get real text without \0x1,\0x2...etc.

Hope this can help who have same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code it will decode perfectly,

```
[self htmlDecode:@"123456\x02\x02"];

-(NSString *)htmlDecode:(NSString *)htmlString
{
    NSData* stringData = [htmlString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSDictionary* options = @{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute:NSHTMLTextDocumentType};
    NSAttributedString* decodedAttributedString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:stringData options:options documentAttributes:NULL error:NULL];
    NSString* decodedString = [decodedAttributedString string];
    NSLog(@"%@",decodedString);
    return decodedString;

}
```